# Как лучше обращатся к БД

Tags: php

Как лучше обращатся к БД ?

1) через вызов функции

```
   function query($request)
 {
$result = mysql_query($request) or die(mysql_error());
 return $result;
 }
```

2)прямо из файла

```
  $result = mysql_query('...');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более гибкий и правильный вариант из 2ух предоставленных - первый. 
Приведу простой пример:

Допустим уже написано много-много кода с использованием самописной и нативной функции запроса. У нас в коде везде используется (о5 таки допустим) `or die(mysql_error())`. И тут мы, явно с горем пополам если так с БД работаем, ну да не суть,  закончили - если ошибка и возникнет мы уже не должны ее выводить. Для этого нам потребуется - перелопатить все до единого скрипты и везде везде закомментировать либо удалить часть `or die(mysql_error())`.

В данном случае, что касается самописной функции - достаточно удалить или закомментировать `or die(mysql_error())` 1 раз и радоваться жизни.

Уже не приятно правда? Но допустим мы писали с использованием `mysql_query`, убрали or die(mysql_error()) и это нас все-равно ничему не научило...

Допустим у нас возникает необходимость логировать все (либо специфические) ошибки mysql. Неважно как мы решим это делать - вызовом самописной функций, либо влоб кодом - нам прийдеться лезть по скриптам и править, править, править...

При использовании самописной функции - достаточно дописать вызов логирования 1 раз.

Ну и, так сказать апофигей - допустим нам надо перенести все на другую СУБД... Тут думаю и продолжать не стоит - все тоже самое.

PS:да и программист должен быть ленивым, зачем постоянно писать mysql_query(), если можно просто query() - 6 лишних букафф :D

Comment: 6 + len( or die(mysql_error()) )

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам важна скорость выполнения скрипта, используйте второй вариант. Если же удобство, используйте первый. Я бы вообще для удобства порекомендовал использовать класс для работы с БД, а не отдельные функции.

Comment: целый ORM тогда уж :-)

Comment: @psyhitus, класса вполне достаточно)

Comment: @Elime, класса всегда недостаточно, можно вообще через ODBC с базой общаться, главное знать толк в извращениях)

Comment: О да, функция вида 
  
      define("DB_DEBUG", true);
      function($query) {
          $res = mysql_query($query);
          if(!$res && DB_DEBUG) die(mysql_error());
          return $res;
      }

Очень тяжелая для php :D. @Elime - с таким подходом вам на ассамблере писать надо а не на php

Класс для работы с БД эт конеш круто, но тогда уже лучше фабрику аля Model, Storage etc. с базовыми методами.

Comment: Кстати - если функция `query()` замедляет работу - то что ее не замедляет? :D
По вашей логике код вида

     function hello($name) {echo 'Hello ' . $name;}
     hello('World'); // серверу хана :DDD

Comment: Умники, а если использовать ее не 1-2 раза? А что если на странице будет пару десятков запросов? а что если будет несколько сотен запросов в секунду? Что вы тогда скажете?

Comment: Скажу что ощутимой разницы не будет, "умник" ;)

Comment: @AlexWindHope, ок

Comment: @Elime - я так понимаю вы мастер невидимого фронта псевдооптимизации? :D

Т.е. если был бы скрипт в котором было бы, например, 50 запросов и нужно было бы оптимизировать производительность - вы бы переписывали query на mysql_query? xD

Если-же нет - к чему вообще это было написано, люди читают и могут подумать что это действительно может пошатнуть производительно.
****
@Elime - пример с большим количеством запросов привел не я, а вы.
Кстати - ваше байтодрочерство было бы пустой тратой времени. Уж что-что а простые 2-3ех строчные функции точно не будут отнимать значительного кол. проц.времени

Comment: Если бы мне дали такой скрипт, я бы даже не брался за эту работу, если там столько запросов, логично, что там будет мягко говоря, код подобен коду пользователя @igolka97. Конечно бы не переписывал, хотя, если бы мне нужно было по максимуму снизить нагрузку, я бы занялся таким байтодрочерством.

-------------------------------------------

ок, удачи

Answer (score 0):

Первый вариант лучше, ведь всегда может понадобиться поменять субд, так же можно в ней отрабатывать исключительные ситуации

Comment: тогда уж лучше PDO использовать

Comment: не обязательно...

Многие не любят PDO по непонятным мне религиозным верованиям.
И все что написал psyhitus - верно.
****
Хотя я и +ую PDO, но вопрос был не об этом.

Comment: впервые услышал про PDO, в чем его проблема? вкусности и так видны)